# What are the best modfiers for the good items on terraria?

Tags: terraria

I am wordering what the best modifier are for the Paladin's Hammer, Vampire knives, Golem fist, and the magical harp?

Comment: I really don't think this is too opinion based. The modifiers are objectively better based on the effect they have on DPS, with few exceptions, and those exceptions are worth discussion. Mana cost is the only thing I can think of that may offset pure DPS in measuring which modifiers are better.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There were no new modifiers added in 1.2, so the modifiers for these items are the same as the ones for their respective classes.

The best modifiers are:

- Godly, for melee weapons that cannot have their speed modified, or for melee weapons that cannot have their size modified. (That means melee weapons that are not swung.)
- Legendary, for other melee weapons
- Demonic, for ranged weapons that have no knockback.
- Unreal, for other ranged weapons.
- Mythical, for magic weapons with knockback.

For magic weapons without knockback, you can choose either Mystic for reduced mana cost, or Demonic for increased damage; there is no clearly better option.

The Paladin's Hammer is a boomerang. Although it is ranged, it does melee damage. Since its speed/size cannot be modified, its best prefix is Godly.

The Vampire Knives, like boomerangs, is a ranged weapon that deals melee damage. Its speed and size also cannot be modified, so its best prefix is Godly.

The Golem Fist looks like it's similar to the Harpoon, in which case it's a ranged weapon with melee damage. Its best prefix is, again, Godly.

The Magical Harp cannot have knockback, so its best modifier is Mystic or Demonic, depending on how you like to play.

<sub>Note: It seems like anything that does not consume ammo deals either melee damage or magic damage, even if it is a ranged weapon.</sub>

Comment: This was very useful information :) But are you sure the hammer can get unreal? i just spent like 150 platinum and still no unreal :/

Comment: I will double-check everything I wrote here momentarily. :)

Comment: @Harrisofunny I'm SO sorry; I forgot boomerangs do melee damage...

Comment: This isn't completely correct.

Comment: @Anthony This is very likely out of date (and may have been partially wrong in the first place). Note that when I wrote this the weapons had just been released and so some of it was conjecture. You are welcome to edit this answer, or even write a new one.

Comment: Ya,whatever you say,doc. =)

Comment: @Schism I mean, it's just...doesn't really make sense.

Comment: this made the weapon modifier page in wiki make so much sense, ty ty

Answer (score 1):

Best modifiers are Godly, Legendary, Unreal, Demonic, Deadly, Murderous, Superior, and Mythical.

### Not all weapons will be shown.

- Melee Weapons
- Godly - Flamerang, Dao of Pow, Gungnir, Dark Lance, Drax
- Legendary - Copper Shortsword, Excalibur, Tizona, Muramasa, Molten Hamaxe, Adamantite Sword, Breaker Blade, Death Sickle, Pwnhammer, Molten Pickaxe, Phasesaber (all colors), Keybrand, Cutlass, Terra Blade, Beam Sword, Horseman's Blade
- Ranged Weopons
- Unreal - Hallowed Repeater, Molten Fury, Minishark, Megashark, Phoenix Blaster, Shotgun, Sniper Rifle, Uzi, Tactical Shotgun
- Godly - Shotgun, Megashark
- Superior - Shotgun
- Murderous - Mythril Repeater, Phoenix Blaster,
- Deadly - Star Cannon, Molten Fury, Stynger
- Demonic - Clockwork Assault Rifle
- Magic Weapons
- Mythical -
  All magic weapons best modifier is Mythical

I apologize if I confused you or did not post what you wanted.
Hope this helped. =)

Comment: I got the information from the wiki.